# Attribute query is not displaying any features & tables

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I am trying to make a demo webgis application, where I can query the attributes of the features. When the run button is clicked, nothing happens. What could be the reason?
btw I'm a beginner and trying to learn webgis following a YouTube tutorial.
[image]

Code

> my code

```
var geojson;
var featureOverlay;

var qryButton = document.createElement("button");
qryButton.innerHTML = '<img src="resources/data-searching.png" alt="" style="width:17px;height:17px;filter:brightness(0) invert(1);vertical-align:middle;"></img>';
qryButton.className = 'myButton';
qryButton.id = 'qryButton';

var qryElement = document.createElement('div');
qryElement.className = 'qryButtonDiv';
qryElement.appendChild(qryButton);

var qryControl = new ol.control.Control({
    element: qryElement
});

var qryFlag = false;

qryButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // disableOtherInteraction('lengthButton'); // Uncomment and replace 'lengthButton' with the appropriate interaction name
    qryButton.classList.toggle('clicked');
    qryFlag = !qryFlag;
    document.getElementById("map").style.cursor = "default";

    if (qryFlag) {
        if (geojson) {
            geojson.getSource().clear();
            map.removeLayer(geojson);
        }

        if (featureOverlay) {
            featureOverlay.getSource().clear();
            map.removeLayer(featureOverlay);
        }
        document.getElementById("map").style.cursor = "default";
        document.getElementById("attQueryDiv").style.display = "block";
        bolIdentify = false;
        addMapLayerList();

    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("map").style.cursor = "default";
        document.getElementById("attQueryDiv").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("attListDiv").style.display = "none";

        if (geojson) {
            geojson.getSource().clear();
            map.removeLayer(geojson);
        }

        if (featureOverlay) {
            featureOverlay.getSource().clear();
            map.removeLayer(featureOverlay);
        }
    }
})
map.addControl(qryControl);

function addMapLayerList() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=getCapabilities",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xml) {
                var select = $('#selectLayer');
                select.append("<option class='ddindent' value=''></option>");

                $(xml).find('FeatureType').each(function () {
                    $(this).find('Name').each(function () {
                        var value = $(this).text();
                        select.append("<option class='ddindent' value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</option>");
                    });
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.error("Error fetching GeoServer capabilities: " + error);
            }
        });
    });
};

$(function () {
    document.getElementById("selectLayer").onchange = function () {
        var select = document.getElementById("selectAttribute");
        while (select.options.length > 0) {
            select.remove(0);
        }

        var value_layer = $(this).val();

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&request=DescribeFeatureType&version=1.1.0&typeName=" + value_layer,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (xml) {
                    var select = $("#selectAttribute");
                    // var title = $(xml).find('xsd\\:complexType').attr('name');
                    // alert(title);
                    select.append("<option class='ddindent' value=''></option>");

                    $(xml).find('xsd\\:sequence').each(function () {
                        $(this).find('xsd\\:element').each(function () {
                            var value = $(this).attr('name');
                            // alert(value);
                            var type = $(this).attr('type');
                            // alert(type);
                            if (value !== 'geom' && value !== 'the_geom') {
                                select.append("<option class='ddindent' value='" + type + "'>" + value + "</option>");
                            }

                        });
                    });
                },

            });
        });
    }

    document.getElementById("selectAttribute").onchange = function () {
        var operator = document.getElementById("selectOperator");
        while (operator.options.length > 0) {
            operator.remove(0);
        }

        var value_type = $(this).val();
        var value_attribute = $('#selectAttribute option:selected').text();

        operator.options[0] = new Option('Select operator', '');

        if (value_type === 'xsd:short' || value_type === 'xsd:int' || value_type === 'xsd:double') {
            operator.options[1] = new Option('Greater than', '>');
            operator.options[2] = new Option('Less than', '<');
            operator.options[3] = new Option('Equal to', '=');
        } else if (value_type === 'xsd:string') {
            operator.options[1] = new Option('Like', 'Like');
            operator.options[2] = new Option('Equal to', '=');
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('attQryRun').onclick = function () {
        map.set("isLoading", "YES");

        if (featureOverlay) {
            featureOverlay.getSource().clear();
            map.removeLayer(featureOverlay);
        }

        var layer = document.getElementById("selectLayer");
        var attribute = document.getElementById("selectAttribute");
        var operator = document.getElementById("selectOperator");
        var txt = document.getElementById("enterValue");

        if (layer.options.selectedIndex == 0) {
            alert("Select Layer");
        } else if (attribute.options.selectedIndex == -1) {
            alert("Select Attribute");
        } else if (operator.options.selectedIndex <= 0) {
            alert("Select Operator");
        } else if (txt.value.length <= 0) {
            alert("Enter Value");
        } else {
            var value_layer = layer.options[layer.selectedIndex].value;
            var value_attribute = attribute.options[attribute.selectedIndex].value;
            var value_operator = operator.options[operator.selectedIndex].value;
            var value_txt = txt.value;

            if (value_operator == 'Like') {
                value_txt = "%25" + value_txt + "%25";
            } else {
                value_txt = value_txt;
            }

            var url =
                "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/WS_Mine/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=" +
                value_layer +
                "&CQL_FILTER=" +
                value_attribute + "+"
            value_operator +
                "+  " +
                value_txt +
                "'&outputFormat=application/json";
            // console.log(url);
            newaddGeoJsonToMap(url);
            newpopulateQueryTable(url);
            setTimeout(function () {
                newaddRowHandlers(url);
            }, 300);
            map.set("isLoading", "NO");
        }

        // Continue with your logic...
    }
});

function newaddGeoJsonToMap(url) {
    if (geojson) {
        geojson.getSource().clear();
        map.removeLayer(geojson);
    }

    var style = new ol.style.Style({
        // fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        //     color: 'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.7)'
        // }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#FFFF00',
            width: 3
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#FFFF00'
            })
        })
    });

    geojson = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: url,
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        }),
        style: style,
    });

    geojson.getSource().on('addfeature', function () {
        map.getView().fit(geojson.getSource().getExtent(), {
            duration: 1500,
            size: map.getSize(),
            maxZoom: 21,
        });
    });

    map.addLayer(geojson);

};  

function newpopulateQueryTable(url) {
    if (typeof attributePanel !== 'undefined') {
        if (attributePanel.parentElement !== null) {
            attributePanel.close();
        }
    }

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        var col = [];
        col.push('id');

        for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
            for (var key in data.features[i].properties) {
                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        table.setAttribute("class", "table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed");
        table.setAttribute("id", "attQryTable");

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement('th');
            th.innerHTML = col[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
        for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
            tr = table.insertRow(-1);

            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                if (j === 0) {
                    tabCell.innerHTML = data.features[i]['id'];
                } else {
                    tabCell.innerHTML = data.features[i].properties[col[j]];
                }
            }
        }

        // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
        var tabDiv = document.getElementById('attListDiv');
        var delTab = document.getElementById('attQryTable');

        if (delTab) {
            tabDiv.removeChild(delTab);
        }

        tabDiv.appendChild(table);
        document.getElementById('attListDiv').style.display = "block";
    }); 
    
    var highlightStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.3)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#FF00FF',
          width: 3
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 10,
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#FF00FF'
          })
        })
    });
      
    var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector(),
        map: map,
        style: highlightStyle
    });
      

};

function newaddRowHandlers() {
    var table = document.getElementById("attQryTable");
    var rows = document.getElementById("attQryTable").rows;
    var heads = table.getElementsByTagName("th");
    var col_no;

    for (var i = 0; i < heads.length; i++) {
        // Take each cell
        var head = heads[i];

        if (head.innerHTML == 'id') {
            col_no = i + 1;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i].onclick = function () {
            return function () {
                featureOverlay.getSource().clear();

                $(function () {
                    $("#attQryTable td").each(function () {
                        $(this).parent("tr").css("background-color", "white");
                    });
                });

                var cell = this.cells[col_no - 1];
                var id = cell.innerHTML;

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#attQryTable td:nth-child(" + col_no + ")").each(function () {
                        if ($(this).text() == id) {
                            $(this).parent("tr").css("background-color", "#d1d8e2");
                        }
                    });
                });

                var features = geojson.getSource().getFeatures();

                for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
                    if (features[i].getId() == id) {
                        featureOverlay.getSource().addFeature(features[i]);
                        featureOverlay.getSource().on('addfeature', function () {
                            map.getView().fit(
                                featureOverlay.getSource().getExtent(),
                                { duration: 1500, size: map.getSize(), maxZoom: 24 }
                            );
                        });
                    }
                }

            };
        }(rows[i]);
    }
}
```

error msg:

> "main.js:864 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null
> (reading 'rows')
> at newaddRowHandlers (main.js:864:54)
> at main.js:731:17"
>
> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<?xml vers"... is not
> valid JSON
> at JSON.parse ()
> at a.onload (featureloader.js:89:23)"

Comment: It looks like you are trying to parse an XML file using a JSON parser. I can't tell if that's what you asked for or if you have an error message but try looking at the response

Comment: Please post error messages as text, not as an image.

Comment: @IanTurton I don't know what it means. By the yt tutorial, it was supposed to display a table as well as highlight the feature as per the query.

Comment: @TomazicM Done.

Comment: the server has sent you an XML file, your code was expecting JSON so it fails to read it. You need to open the XML file and see what is in it

Comment: Usually when you request application/json from Geoserver and get XML instead it is an error message.